# Serial connection Woes

Tags: setup

I was wondering if anyone could provide assistance or explanations for my pi woes.

I have a pi with a formatted microsd card that I got from adafruit.  I do not have an HDMI monitor so I have been trying to connect it via serial cable. I followed the guide here for setup: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/overview

When I try it on my Linux machine using Screen, the computer does not mount it. When I try it on my PC via putty (and after installing appropriate drivers), it tells me "unable to open serial port."

Am I missing something obvious?

ls /dev (with the console cable plugged in), returns:

Comment: Can you provide the directory listing for `/dev` on your linux machine?. For example,  `ls /dev` and post the output in original post. On my mac, I see `tty.usbserial-AM01R12Y` for my console cable. Yours may be something like `ttyUSB0`. This is the address you will use when connecting.

Comment: Hi,thanks.  Did you want the entire /dev directory (which I don't quite know how to format on here), or just the "console" line?  If the latter, it reads: "console  port       sr0       tty36  ttyS0  urandom"

Comment: Just post ls /dev/cu.* results

Comment: I get "no such file or directory" for /dev/cu.* but /dev/cu* gives me "/dev/cuse"  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: No. It doesn't look like the drivers are installed. Your device should be listed in `/dev` with `cu.XXXX`

Answer (score 1):

Hang on.

Looks like your drivers are not installed properly.

The Mac/Linux  should show it in /dev simply take a snapshot with and without the cable attached and see if it changes. You may find minicom easier than screen.

The PC will show it in the device manager.

No point trying software on either unless that has been achieved.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a particular place to get the drivers?  For the PC, I followed the instructions on the Adafruit pdf.  When I look at it in the PC device manager, there is a "!" with the icon and when I go to "properties," it tells me "This device cannot start (Code 10) A device wich does not exist was specified."  Which, according to http://superuser.com/questions/544485/this-device-cannot-start-code-10-gigaware-usb-serial-adapter, the chip is not accepted by Windows 8.

Comment: If it helps, in linux, when I try lsusb with the pi cable connected, it seems to appear as: "Bus 004 Device 010: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port"

Comment: According to the Prolific site (http://prolificusa.com/pl-2303hx-drivers/): "PL-2303 Linux Driver for RedHat 7.3/8.0/9.0 Only
NOTE: No need to install drivers for following:
Linux Kernel 2.4.31 and above already includes built-in drivers for PL-2303 (VID_067B&PID_2303)."